# Cassandra and solr on same node

Tags: solr, cassandra

I am working on architecting a POC Cassandra Datastax enterprise cluster environment. We are going to use solr in combination with Cassandra. Would it be a valid configuration to host both solr and Cassandra on the same physical server?

Answer (score 2):

If you're evaluating DSE, Solr is built into the packages you're using. It's an extremely tight integration that would be tough to replicate on your own. Here's the documentation: https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchIntro.html

It's also worth noting that Solr, in this case, does run co-located with Cassandra for data locality, and to take advantage of C* replication, availability, and some other C* specific benefits.

But most importantly I suggest checking out this hands on training: https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds310-datastax-enterprise-search-apache-solr

If you have any specific questions about the integration, update your question and I'd be happy to help.